# MVVM ICommand.CanExecute parameter contains previous value

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, icommand, delegatecommand

I've a hard time understanding why ICommand.CanExecutes always contains the previous value instead of the new value if a nested property is used instead of a normal property.

The problem is described below and I seriously can't figure out a way to fix this besides using some form of "Facade" pattern where I create properties in the viewmodel and hook them to their corresponding property in the model.

Or use the damn CommandManager.RequerySuggested event. The reason this is not optimal is because the view presents over 30 commands, just counting the menu, and if all CanExecute updates every time something changes, it will take a few seconds for all menuitems / buttons to update. Even using the example down below with only a single command and button together with the command manager it takes around 500ms for the button to enable/disable itself.

The only reason I can think of is that the CommandParameter binding is not updated before the CanExecute is fired and then I guess there is nothing you can do about it.

Thanks in advance :!

**For example**

Let's say we've this basic viewmodel

```
public class BasicViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set {
            this.name = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Name");
            Command.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
        }
    }

    private Project project;

    public Project Project
    {
        get { return project; }
        set {
            if (project != null) project.PropertyChanged -= ChildPropertyChanged;
            if (value != null) value.PropertyChanged += ChildPropertyChanged;

            project = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Project");
        }
    }

    private void ChildPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
        Command.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
    }

    public DelegateCommand<string> Command { get; set; }

    public BasicViewModel()
    {
        this.Project = new Example.Project();
        Command = new DelegateCommand<string>(this.Execute, this.CanExecute);
    }

    private bool CanExecute(string arg) {
        return !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(arg);
    }

    private void Execute(string obj) { }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName = null) {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

and this model

```
public class Project : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string text;

    public string Text
    {
        get { return text; }
        set
        {
            text = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Text");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Now in my view I've this textbox and button.

```
<Button Content="Button" CommandParameter="{Binding Path=Project.Text}" Command="{Binding Path=Command}" />
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Project.Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

It works, every time I type something in the textbox the CanExecute is invoked, BUT the parameter is always set to the previous value. Let say I write 'H' in the textbox, CanExecute is fired with parameter set to NULL. Next I write 'E', now the textbox contains "HE" and the CanExecute fires again. This time with the parameter set to 'H' only.

For some strange reason the parameter is always set to the previous value and when I check the Project.Text it's set to "HE" but parameter is still set to only 'H'.

If I now change the command parameter to

```
CommandParameter="{Binding Path=Name}"
```

and the Textbox.Text to

```
Text={Binding Path=Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

everything works perfectly. The CanExecute parameter always contain the latest value and not the previous value.

Comment: You should place all example code for VM in the question, not refer to external sites like pastebin

Comment: @AwkwardCoder Updated with all code in the question, the reason I did this was to keep the question as short as possible but I understand how it can be hard to follow the question.

Comment: Firstly, you shouldn't need the calls to Command.RaiseCanExecuteChanged() in the ViewModel, re-evaluation of the bound commands should happen automatically.

Comment: Secondly, if you're binding the TextBox to a property in the ViewModel you don't have to pass the parameter back using a CommandParameter in the XAML, it is superfluous, I would either not pass a command parameter and bind the TextBox or not bind the TextBox and pass the text value as a CommandParameter.

Comment: @AwkwardCoder hmm, if I bind the parameter to the textbox.Text directly, then I need to create a event handler for the TextChanged event and then invoke CanExecute every time the text changes, feels like too much code in the back-end but I'll try to figure out a solution without going the CommandManager route.

Comment: no you don't, from what I believe you want I've posted the example code as an answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this great attached property from swythan on the prism codeplex discussion forum that did the trick very well. Of course it does not answer why the command parameter is set to the previous value but it fixes the problem in a nice way.

The code is slightly modified from the source, enabling the possibility to use it on controls in a TabItem by calling HookCommandParameterChanged when the OnLoaded event is invoked.

```
public static class CommandParameterBehavior
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsCommandRequeriedOnChangeProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsCommandRequeriedOnChange",
                                            typeof(bool),
                                            typeof(CommandParameterBehavior),
                                            new UIPropertyMetadata(false, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnIsCommandRequeriedOnChangeChanged)));

    public static bool GetIsCommandRequeriedOnChange(DependencyObject target)
    {
        return (bool)target.GetValue(IsCommandRequeriedOnChangeProperty);
    }

    public static void SetIsCommandRequeriedOnChange(DependencyObject target, bool value)
    {
        target.SetValue(IsCommandRequeriedOnChangeProperty, value);
    }

    private static void OnIsCommandRequeriedOnChangeChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!(d is ICommandSource))
            return;

        if (!(d is FrameworkElement || d is FrameworkContentElement))
            return;

        if ((bool)e.NewValue)
            HookCommandParameterChanged(d);
        else
            UnhookCommandParameterChanged(d);

        UpdateCommandState(d);
    }

    private static PropertyDescriptor GetCommandParameterPropertyDescriptor(object source)
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(source.GetType())["CommandParameter"];
    }

    private static void HookCommandParameterChanged(object source)
    {
        var propertyDescriptor = GetCommandParameterPropertyDescriptor(source);
        propertyDescriptor.AddValueChanged(source, OnCommandParameterChanged);

        // N.B. Using PropertyDescriptor.AddValueChanged will cause "source" to never be garbage collected,
        // so we need to hook the Unloaded event and call RemoveValueChanged there.
        HookUnloaded(source);
    }

    private static void UnhookCommandParameterChanged(object source)
    {
        var propertyDescriptor = GetCommandParameterPropertyDescriptor(source);
        propertyDescriptor.RemoveValueChanged(source, OnCommandParameterChanged);

        UnhookUnloaded(source);
    }

    private static void HookUnloaded(object source)
    {
        var fe = source as FrameworkElement;
        if (fe != null)
        {
            fe.Unloaded += OnUnloaded;
            fe.Loaded -= OnLoaded;
        }

        var fce = source as FrameworkContentElement;
        if (fce != null)
        {
            fce.Unloaded += OnUnloaded;
            fce.Loaded -= OnLoaded;
        }
    }

    private static void UnhookUnloaded(object source)
    {
        var fe = source as FrameworkElement;
        if (fe != null)
        {
            fe.Unloaded -= OnUnloaded;
            fe.Loaded += OnLoaded;
        }

        var fce = source as FrameworkContentElement;
        if (fce != null)
        {
            fce.Unloaded -= OnUnloaded;
            fce.Loaded += OnLoaded;
        }
    }

    static void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        HookCommandParameterChanged(sender);
    }

    static void OnUnloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        UnhookCommandParameterChanged(sender);
    }

    static void OnCommandParameterChanged(object sender, EventArgs ea)
    {
        UpdateCommandState(sender);
    }

    private static void UpdateCommandState(object target)
    {
        var commandSource = target as ICommandSource;

        if (commandSource == null)
            return;

        var rc = commandSource.Command as RoutedCommand;
        if (rc != null)
            CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();

        var dc = commandSource.Command as IDelegateCommand;
        if (dc != null)
            dc.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
    }
}
```

Source: https://compositewpf.codeplex.com/discussions/47338

Answer (score 0):

The facade pattern you're talking about it standard WPF practice. The main problem with the way that you're doing it is that when events are raised, their subscribed event handlers execute in the order that they are subscribed. The line of code where you have:

```
        if (value != null) value.PropertyChanged += ChildPropertyChanged;
```

This subscribes to the "PropertyChanged" Event of your "Project" class. Your UIElements are also subscribed to this same "PropertyChanged" event through your binding in the XAML. In short, your "PropertyChanged" event now has 2 subscribers.

The thing about events is that they fire in a sequence and what's happening in your code, is that when the event fires from your "Project.Text" it executes your "ChildPropertyChanged" event, firing your "CanExecuteChanged" event, which finally runs your "CanExecute" function(which is when you're seeing the incorrect parameter). 
THEN, after that, your UIElements get their EventHandlers executed by that same event. And their values get updated.

It's the order of your subscriptions causing the problem. Try this and tell me if it fixes your problem:

```
public Project Project
{
    get { return project; }
    set {
        if (project != null) project.PropertyChanged -= ChildPropertyChanged;
        project = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("Project");
        if (project != null) project.PropertyChanged += ChildPropertyChanged;
    }
}
```

Comment: Makes no difference since we're chaning Project.Text and not the Project. The set method of the Project is only set once, during the construction when the Project instance is created. Anyway I tried it and it made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would have done this, and it works as expected. The only difference here is I'm using RelayCommand instead of DelegateCommand - they fundamentally have the same implementation so they should be interchangeable.

When the user enters the text and then clicks the button the execute method of the RelayCommand gets the expected text - simple.

XAML:

```
<Grid>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBox Grid.Column="0"
             Grid.Row="0"
             Text="{Binding Path=Text, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />

    <Button Grid.Column="0"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Content="Test"
            VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            Command="{Binding Path=TextCommand, Mode=OneWay}" />

</Grid>
```

ViewModel:

```
public sealed class ExampleViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private string _text;

    public ExampleViewModel()
    {
       TextCommand = new RelayCommand(TextExecute, CanTextExecute);
    }

    public string Text
    {
        get
        {
            return _text;
        }
        set
        {
            _text = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Text");
        }
    }

    public ICommand TextCommand { get; private set; }

    private void TextExecute()
    {
        // Do something with _text value...
    }

    private bool CanTextExecute()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```